# How to find and replace before the match?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, vi, regex-lookarounds

I have comma delimited data like 12345,6789,567890. What i would like is to find 3 digits before the first comma and put a comma where they start. Given the above entry, i want to find 3 digits before first comma, that would be 345 and transform the entry "12345" to "12,345".

What is the regular expression to find 3 digits before first comma occurrence and how to put comma before those 3 digits. I am using vim.

Comment: Why tagging with `perl`?

Comment: (1) That changes your data then -- that line will then have six fields (if you insert a comma and not, say, period). Is that what you want? (2) What when a number is longer than 6 digits: do you keep going, so inserting two commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find and replace you need to capture the groups. The regular expression that allows you to do this is:

```
(\d{3},)([\d,]*)
```

But, to be able to use it to find and replace in `vim` you need simple modification since it requires to skip the first curly bracket of the quantifier. Then, you can just insert the coma before the whole match. You can use directly the following statement in `vim`:

```
.s/\d\{3},[\d,]*/,\0/
```

As a brief explanation, `\d\{3},` allows you to match exactly the three previous digits before the first comma and the comma. Then the rest of the regex allows you to capture the trailing part. Finally, in `vim` the `,\0` allows you to set a comma just before the full match.

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged with perl, so you could do:

```
echo '12345,6789,567890' | perl -pe 's/^[^,]*\K(?=\d{3},)/,/'
12,345,6789,567890
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  [^,]*         # 0 or more any character but comma
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  (?=           # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \d{3}       # 3 digits
    ,           # a comma
  )             # end lookahead
```